# Ionic2: Unable to set distance and duration from google directions service API

Tags: google-maps, ionic2

Need help with Google Directions Service with ionic2. I am trying to set the distance and duration variables after calculating it via the route function. The value is coming as undefined when i access in another method (like the onClickMap here).

Below is the code that I have created:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';

declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-activity-detail',
  templateUrl: 'activity-detail.html',
})
export class ActivityDetailPage {

  public dist: any;
  public dur: any;
  latLng: any;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public geolocation: Geolocation) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
        this.latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        let destination = new google.maps.LatLng(this.activity.address.latitude, this.activity.address.longitude);
        let directionService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        directionService.route({
            origin: this.latLng,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
            provideRouteAlternatives: false
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                let t = 0;
                let d = 0;
                let myroute = response.routes[0];
                console.log(myroute);
                for (let i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
                    t += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
                    d += myroute.legs[i].duration.value;
                }

                this.dist = t / 1000;
                this.dur = d /60;
            } else {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

  }
  onClickMap(){
    alert(this.dist);
    alert(this.dur);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a complete example that demonstrates the issue? Are you sure that Directions service returns an OK status?

Comment: I updated the code for the entire ts file here.

(1). Yes status is OK for the directions service
(2). I am able to alert / console.log the values right after it is set and it shows the correct value
(3). When I am trying to access it in the other onClickMap method or elsewhere, I get undefined.